# Move and copy text file in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, directory, copy, move

I referred to all the previous responses to this question from stackoverflow and tried out the following. But unfortunately, I am still encountering an issue.

I have a text file named `Rels_obs` inside my directory `home/manuela/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data`. As the script runs, it extracts a `kgis.tar.gz` compressed folder and extracts it in the following manner.

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly DATA_URL='https://linqs-data.soe.ucsc.edu/public/psl-examples-data/kgi.tar.gz'
readonly DATA_FILE='kgis.tar.gz'
readonly DATA_DIR='kgi'

function main() {
   trap exit SIGINT

   check_requirements

   fetch_file "${DATA_URL}" "${DATA_FILE}" 'data'
   extract_tar "${DATA_FILE}" "${DATA_DIR}" 'data'
}
```

The extraction results in two directories within the data directory found at `home/manuela/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data` :

- eval directory : `home/manuela/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/eval`
- learn directory : `home/manuela/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/learn`

What I want to do is to copy my `Rels_obs` file to both of these newly available directories, `eval` and `learn`.

I tried doing the following but it resulted in an error as shown below.

```
#!/bin/bash

readonly DATA_URL='https://linqs-data.soe.ucsc.edu/public/psl-examples-data/kgi.tar.gz'
readonly DATA_FILE='kgis.tar.gz'
readonly DATA_DIR='kgi'

function main() {
   trap exit SIGINT

   check_requirements

   fetch_file "${DATA_URL}" "${DATA_FILE}" 'data'
   extract_tar "${DATA_FILE}" "${DATA_DIR}" 'data'

   echo "COPYING"

   //I have only one file that is of plain text format within the data directory

   for file in ~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/*.txt
    do  
        name="$(basename "$file" .txt)"
        cp "$file" "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/eval"
        cp "$file" "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/learn"
    done
    echo "SUCCESSFULLY COPIED FILES"
}
```

**Error**

> COPYING
>   cp: cannot stat '/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/*.txt': No such file or directory
>   cp: cannot stat '/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/*.txt': No such file or directory

**ls -l on the data directory**

```
total 20524
-rwxr-xr-x 1 manuelanayantarajeyaraj manuelanayantarajeyaraj     2210 
Feb  5 15:19 fetchData.sh
drwxrwxr-x 4 manuelanayantarajeyaraj manuelanayantarajeyaraj     4096 
Nov 19  2017 kgi
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manuelanayantarajeyaraj manuelanayantarajeyaraj 18546351 
Feb  5 15:21 kgis.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- 1 manuelanayantarajeyaraj manuelanayantarajeyaraj  2459319 
Feb  5 13:31 Rels_obs
```

Any suggestions in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a text file named `Rels_obs`, but is it named that or is it named `Rels_obs.txt`? Linux (text) files do not need an extension per se, extensions are purely for the user's convenience. So if the file does not have the extension, this script will not find it since it is looking for the extension.

If you're sure this file will always have the same name, and you only want this file, I'd simply use the name.

ie.

```
cp "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/Rels_obs" "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/eval"
cp "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/Rels_obs" "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/learn"
```

If you really want all plaintext files in that directory, you could do this:

```
for file in ~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/*
    do
        test "`file $file`" =~ "ASCII text" || continue
        cp "$file" "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/eval"
        cp "$file" "~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/kgi/learn"
    done
```

Or you could rename the file to add the .txt extension first somehow.

Comment: In that case, how can I copy this file? It says that the file is of "Plain text document" format in its properties.

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer this since it was too long to put in a comment reply.

Comment: I just saw your reply to @milan-dufek's answer; could you post the output of
`ls -l ~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data//Rels_obs.txt ; file ~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data//Rels_obs.txt` ? (or without the .txt extension if you've since renamed it back)

Comment: I renamed it when I was replying to @Milan-dufek. But now I simply have Rels_obs and tried your first suggestion. But I seem to be getting `cp: cannot stat 'home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/Rels_obs': No such file or directory`. I've updated my question with the ls -l output.

Comment: I notice there's no / at the beginning of the path in your error this time. is that something that could cause the issue? Is everything copied and pasted correctly, '~' characters and all?

Comment: From my end, it seems as if I've tried altering in various ways. So currently I am trying a different approach of getting the file into the rather than copying. I'll check if it works and get back to you. But Thanks a million for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

It says no such file or directory, which is visible from the file name: 
*/home/manuelanayantarajeyaraj/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/.txt*
It doesn't parse an asterisk in the for loop.

As a hot fix you can use:

```
SRC_DIR="~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/"
for file in $(ls -1 ${SRC_DIR}/*.txt); do  
    cp "$file" "${SRC_DIR}/kgi/eval"
    cp "$file" "${SRC_DIR}/kgi/learn"
done
echo "SUCCESSFULLY COPIED FILES"
```

Or you can just copy then by two commands:

```
SRC_DIR="~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data/"
cp ${SRC_DIR}/*.txt ${SRC_DIR}/kgi/eval/
cp ${SRC_DIR}/*.txt ${SRC_DIR}/kgi/learn/
```

Comment: Hi Milan, Thanks for your response. I tried this and it did not work. I got the same error. I think the error is because of the extension as @jvdmr mentioned. So I tried renaming the file as `Rels_obs.txt` and modified your suggestion as `cp ${SRC_DIR}/Rels_obs.txt ${SRC_DIR}/kgi/eval/`. But this returned the same error as *"cp: cannot stat '~/PycharmProjects/knowledgegraphidentification/data//Rels_obs.txt': No such file or directory"*